# Android: Getting null value after onPostExecute

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

This question is continuation of my previous question. The link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12499941/android-getting-wrong-info-on-parsing-json-data#comment16829891_12499941
The problem I am facing is, in doInBackground of Async Task, I am able to put data in NearLocation[]. Then, I passed this array to onPostExecute(). There I printed the data in NearLocation[], and it gave me the result whatever it had in array. This array, I am using in SitesOverlay class. Also, I am using this array in onCreate of activity to check whether it contains value. If not, it should give me an alert message. When I run my app, it showed NearLocation[] is null and gave me alert. But, at that time value was there in the array, I checked the same in onPostExecute. Now, I am not understanding, how the array became null, when it was having value in onPostExecute(). Did, i did anything wrong. I tried and searched a lot but couldn't come up with solution. I am posting my updated code below as well as.

**Activity class**

```
public class TrackDriverActivity extends MapActivity {

Button btnCurrLoc;
EditText txtPickAddress;
MapView map;

MapController mc;
GeoPoint p;
boolean foundValidLocation = true;
public NearLocation[] nearLocations;
public String driverLatitude;
public String driverLongitude;
private MyLocationOverlay me=null;
private static final String TAG = "TrackDriverActivity";
String tripstatus;
/**
 * Nitish
 * Tue 11 Sep 2012 06:57 PM
 * */
private final String url = "http://towncarapp.com/android/near_driver.php?email="+ UserProfile.email;
JSONObject jsonObject;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.trackdriver);

    Log.v(TAG,"Inside Pick Location Activity");
    new LoadDriverDetailsAsyncTask(TrackDriverActivity.this, url).execute();

    map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapLocation);

    if(nearLocations!=null && nearLocations.length !=0)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nearLocations.length; i++)
        {
            NearLocation driverLocation = nearLocations[i];
            driverLatitude = driverLocation.lat;
            driverLatitude = driverLocation.lon;
            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude = " +driverLatitude);
            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude = " +driverLongitude);
        }//for
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate nearLocation if");
    }//if
    else
    {
        TownCarDialogManager.showOkOnlyDialog(TrackDriverActivity.this, "Message", "No Driver assigned yet.");
        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(39.83,-98.58));
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate nearLocation else");
    }//else
    // First Get the current location
    Location currentLocation = getCurrentLocation();

    Log.v(TAG,"Till Current Location");
    if (currentLocation != null) 
    { 
        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude()));

        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
        marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
        marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

        try {
            map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker, getPoint(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude())));
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        map.invalidate();
    }//if 
    else 
    {
        Log.v("","No Current Location Found");
    }//else


    Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker2); //Driver Marker   
    marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
    marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

    try {
        map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker, null));
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }



    map.getController().setZoom(17); 
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.invalidate();

    /***/

    if (nearLocations == null || nearLocations.length <= 0) 
    {
        //showDialog("Sorry!!!","No driver has been assigned yet.",this);
        TownCarDialogManager.showOkOnlyPostProcessingDialog(TrackDriverActivity.this, "Message", "No Driver assigned yet.", 3);
        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint(39.83,-98.58));
        //map.getController().zoomToSpan(Integer.parseInt(nearLocations[0].lat),Integer.parseInt(nearLocations[0].lon));
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    }//if


}//onCreate

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}//isRouteDisplayed

public Location getCurrentLocation()
{
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) TrackDriverActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria locCriteria = new Criteria();
    locCriteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
    Location lastLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(locCriteria, true));
    return lastLocation;        
}//getCurrentLocation

public String getCurrentLocationAddess()
{
    Location currentLocation = getCurrentLocation();
    String addressString = null;        

    if(currentLocation!=null)
    {
        Geocoder gc = new Geocoder(TrackDriverActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        try 
        {
            List<Address> addresses = gc.getFromLocation(currentLocation.getLatitude(), currentLocation.getLongitude(), 1);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            if (addresses.size() > 0) 
            {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++)
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");

                sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            }//if
            addressString = sb.toString();
        }//try 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.v("SelectPickupLocation","getCurrentLocationAddress::IOException ");
        }//catch
    }//if
    return addressString;
}//getCurrentLocationAddress

private double getDouble(String dbl){
    Double d;

    try{
        d = Double.valueOf(dbl);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return 0;
    }

    System.out.println("***"+d);

    return d.doubleValue();
}

private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
    return (new GeoPoint((int) (lat * 1000000.0), (int) (lon * 1000000.0)));
}   

private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
    private List<OverlayItem> items = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker, GeoPoint center) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        super(marker);
        boundCenterBottom(marker);

        if (center != null){
            items.add(new OverlayItem(center, "" , ""+getCurrentLocationAddess()));
        } else {
            //nearLocations = getNearLocations(jsonObject);
                if (nearLocations != null && nearLocations.length > 0 ) {
                Log.v("","+"+nearLocations.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < nearLocations.length; i++){
                    NearLocation loc = nearLocations[i];
                    Log.v(TAG,"*"+loc.lat+"*"+loc.lon);
                    items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint(getDouble(driverLatitude), getDouble(driverLongitude)),"", "Driver Location"));                  
                }
            }
        }

        populate();
    }

    @Override
    protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
        return (items.get(i));
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onTap(int i) {
        Toast.makeText(TrackDriverActivity.this, items.get(i).getSnippet(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        return (true);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return (items.size());
    }
}

private class LoadDriverDetailsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, NearLocation[]>
{
    private ProgressDialog pd;
    Context ctx;
    String url;
    public LoadDriverDetailsAsyncTask(Context ctx, String url)
    {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.url = url;
    }//Constructor

    protected void onPreExecute() 
    {
        super.onPreExecute();

        pd=new ProgressDialog(ctx);
        pd.setMessage("Please Wait...");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }//onPreExecute

    protected NearLocation[] doInBackground(String... params) 
    {
        JSONObject jObject = JSONParser.getJSONObjectDataFromURL(url);  
        nearLocations = getNearLocations(jObject);
        return nearLocations;
    }//doInBackground

    protected void onPostExecute(NearLocation[] nearLocations) 
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < nearLocations.length; i++){
            NearLocation loc = nearLocations[i];
            Log.d("LoadDriverAsyncTaskDriverlATITUDE", loc.lat);
            Log.d("LoadDriverAsyncTaskDriverlongitude", loc.lon);
        }
        pd.dismiss();
    }//onPostExecute
}//LoadMapAsyncTask

public NearLocation[] getNearLocations(JSONObject jObject) 
{
    NearLocation[] nearLocation = null;

    try
    {
        if(jObject!=null)
        {
            JSONArray jsonArray = jObject.getJSONArray("statement");

            if (jsonArray != null) 
            {
                nearLocation = new NearLocation[jsonArray.length()];
                Log.v(TAG, "::::::&&&&&&&&&&&&&::::::NearLocations "
                    + nearLocation.length);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
                {
                    JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    NearLocation loc = new NearLocation(
                            e.getString("latitude"),
                            e.getString("longitude"));
                    nearLocation[i] = loc;
                    Log.v("Driver latitude:", loc.lat);
                    Log.v("Driver longitude:", loc.lon);
                }//for
            }//if
        }//if
        else
        {
            TownCarDialogManager.showOkOnlyDialog(TrackDriverActivity.this, "Sorry", "There is problem in internet connection");
        }//else
    }//try 
    catch (JSONException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }//catch

    return nearLocation;
}//getNearLocations

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem you have, but here are some issues with your code, see if they solve the problem. They way you setup the code(especially the `AsyncTask`) might work in some cases but it will fail in most. In the `onCreate` method you instantiate the task and then you call `execute()` to start it. At this moment the code in the `onCreate` method will continue to be run(and the task will do the same), but as the task most likely hasn't finished getting the data, the `nearlocations` array will be `null`. So the problem is that you don't wait to let the task to finish getting the data so you end up using the null `nearLocations` variable. One way to avoid this is to use a callback system. Below is an example:

```
// this is an interface that the TrackDriverActivity will implement
interface OnLoadDriverDetails {
     onLoadDriverDetails(NearLocation[] data); 
}
```

this callback will be called from the `AsyncTask` when it finishes loading the data:

```
private class LoadDriverDetailsAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, NearLocation[]> {

    OnLoadDriverDetails mListener;

    public LoadDriverDetailsAsyncTask(Context ctx, String url) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.url = url;
        mListener = (OnLoadDriverDetails) ctx;
    }

    protected NearLocation[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        JSONObject jObject = JSONParser.getJSONObjectDataFromURL(url);          
        return getNearLocations(jObject);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(NearLocation[] nearLocations) {
         mListener.onLoadDriverDetails(newrLocations);
    }
    // the rest of the task's code
```

In the activity you'll move the code from `onCreate` that needs the valid `nearLocations` array in the `onLoadDriverDetails` callback:

```
public class TrackDriverActivity extends MapActivity implements OnLoadDriverDetails {

    // ...
    public void onLoadDriverDetails(NearLocation[] data) {
        nearLocations = data;
        // here do the things you do in the onCreate method like setting those SitesOverlay items on the map
    }
```

Comment: thanks, it worked for me. But, I want to know in which case we should use callback system, as I am not clear with the concepts.

Comment: @Nitish You'll generally use this callback system when you need to have an action done(creating views, updating views, populating with data, showing notifications etc) when a particular event happens(like the data has finished loading, the user clicks something etc), just like a listener.